# Need Stack Exchange for Bodybuilding / Fitness / Nutrition

Tags: discussion

I am suggesting the owners of Stack Exchange to start a satellite site for bodybuilding/fitness/nutrition. I have yet to find a good forum for discussing these topics. [Bodybuilding.com](http://bodybuilding.com) has the biggest forum but it's full of trolls, the answers are unreliable, and the UI sucks.

[image]

Comment: Proposals for new sites should go to our Area 51 site. You can read about that process here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

You can [propose a site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=life) yourself on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), and it looks like there is [already one for Body Building](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14912/body-building)